# Flextable Formating for proper row and column look and feel

Tags: gwt, uibinder, flextable

I have to create a Flextable which would take values from the backend. So it is supposed to have no rows but only columns till that call is made. When I create a flextable using the uibinder

```
table.setText(0, 0, "Name");
table.setText(0, 1, "Birthdate");
table.setText(0, 2, "Address");
```

The whole column space is used and I am unable to get any defined rows.How can I get only the column header names till the time the values are received from backend so that it has a better look and feel.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [CellTable](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) or [DataGrid](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) widget when you need to display multiple rows of data with column headers. These widgets are specifically designed for this purpose.

If, for some reason, you prefer to use a FlexTabel, use CSS to style the header row (height, line-height, etc.)